# Android GridView vertical borders

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I'm trying to get borders between my fragments showing in a `GridView`.
I setted the background color of the `GridView` to white and that of the fragments to black.
Then I inserted those code lines:

```
int border = 2; // px
view.setColumnWidth((dm.widthPixels / 2)-(4*border));
view.setNumColumns(2);
view.setHorizontalSpacing(border);
view.setVerticalSpacing(border);
```

`view` is my `GridView`.

The result is nice borders at the left of the whole `GridView` and between the fragments on top and at the bottom.
But between the both fragments on top there is no border.

Here is my declaration of the `GridView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/overview"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:clipChildren="true" >

</GridView>
```

May be somebody can help.

Greets

Comment: Can you not simply set some padding or a (9patch) drawable as background to the layout of your grid items?

Comment: I completely do not understand your hint. Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @Henrik: I added my explanation as answer, since it wasn't going to fit on a couple of lines. :) By the way, please add `@<author>` (e.g. `@MH.`) next time you reply to a comment, as then that person will get notified of your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, what I was trying to explain in my earlier comment: in stead of having the `GridView` regulate the spacing you want, why don't you try to make the grid items take care of that? One easy solution for this is by setting an appropriate drawable as background to the layout file you're using in/passing into the `GridView`'s adapter - in other words: the layout you use for your grid items, which in your case will be the fragments you mentioned.

A quick example:

Take a `GridView`:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:numColumns="4" />
```

And an layout to be used for the item inside of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

And finally, the magic from a background drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />    
    <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />    
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />    
</shape>
```

The result will then be:

[image: gridview with 'borders']

I'm not sure why the horizontal and vertical spacing parameters don't work for you, by the way. When I use those, I'm able to get an effect pretty similar to that in the image above:

`GridView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
```

Item layout (simply swapped out the earlier background resource for a fixed colour):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Result:

[image: another gridview with 'borders']

Hope this will help you on your way.

Comment: I tried both solutions but none of them worked. I inserted the "android:background="@drawable/grid_layout"" statement into the outer LinearLayout of the Fragments. was that correct?

Comment: Sorry your solution with grid_layout works fine! I found a line in my fragment codes where I set the background color. removed this line everything is perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: What if I am using adapter to set the TextViews? should I put the XML of the TextView also?

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy: I'm not sure what you're asking? There should be no difference between inflating or instantiating the `TextView` from within the adapter, as long as you set the relevant attributes correctly.